# Convert to fraction inches

Tags: c#, math, fractions

I need to convert a double value (centimeters) to a fraction value with this format: 3 1/64 (inches). After reading a lot about this and finding algorithms for converting into fractions, I think they are not good for what I need, because my fractions should be in these formats: ?/2, ?/4, ?/8, ?/16, ?/32, ?/64. I have seen conversion tables like this: [table](https://mdmetric.com/tech/cvtchtfdm.htm). And I think my best solution is to create a key, value list with all values in the table and for each number find the best approximation in the list.

For example: 3.21 cm. = 1.26378 in = 1 in + 0.26378. So, according the table linked, 0.26378 = 17/64. And the final result should be 1 17/64 inches.

So my questions are:

1. Is a good idea to have a list with the values in the table and find the closest value in order to give the fraction or it is better to create an algorithm for this?
2. In case it is fine to create a list with the values, how can I find the closest value of a given number in my list?

Comment: problem with a table is, what if you get a value bigger than any represented by the table? There's nothing wrong with using an algorithm - you'll get a more accurate answer. If you need to show it to the user in a certain format, there'll be a mathematical way of working out what that should look like too

Comment: No. Your problem can be defined simply in binary. Then just convert the binary expansion into a fraction, by left shifting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using simple math instead of table

```
private static string ToFraction64(double value) {
  // denominator is fixed
  int denominator = 64;
  // integer part, can be signed: 1, 0, -3,...
  int integer = (int) value;
  // numerator: always unsigned (the sign belongs to the integer part)
  // + 0.5 - rounding, nearest one: 37.9 / 64 -> 38 / 64; 38.01 / 64 -> 38 / 64
  int numerator = (int) ((Math.Abs(value) - Math.Abs(integer)) * denominator + 0.5);

  // some fractions, e.g. 24 / 64 can be simplified:
  // both numerator and denominator can be divided by the same number
  // since 64 = 2 ** 6 we can try 2 powers only 
  // 24/64 -> 12/32 -> 6/16 -> 3/8
  // In general case (arbitrary denominator) use gcd (Greatest Common Divisor):
  //   double factor = gcd(denominator, numerator);
  //   denominator /= factor;
  //   numerator /= factor;
  while ((numerator % 2 == 0) && (denominator % 2 == 0)) {
    numerator /= 2;
    denominator /= 2;
  }

  // The longest part is formatting out

  // if we have an actual, not degenerated fraction (not, say, 4 0/1)
  if (denominator > 1)
    if (integer != 0) // all three: integer + numerator + denominator
      return string.Format("{0} {1}/{2}", integer, numerator, denominator);
    else if (value < 0) // negative numerator/denominator, e.g. -1/4
      return string.Format("-{0}/{1}", numerator, denominator);
    else // positive numerator/denominator, e.g. 3/8
      return string.Format("{0}/{1}", numerator, denominator);
  else 
    return integer.ToString(); // just an integer value, e.g. 0, -3, 12...  
}
```

Tests

```
const double cmInInch = 2.54;

// 1 17/64
Console.Write(ToFraction64(3.21 / cmInInch));
// -1 17/64
Console.Write(ToFraction64(-1.26378));
// 3 1/4
Console.Write(ToFraction64(3.25001));
// 3 1/4
Console.Write(ToFraction64(3.24997));
// 5
Console.Write(ToFraction64(5.000001));
// -1/8
Console.Write(ToFraction64(-0.129));
// 1/8
Console.Write(ToFraction64(0.129));
```

Comment: The question lacks explanation of algorithm. Do you iterate denominators starting from `64` all the way down (32, 16, ... 2) and checking error to find the best match or what? Or is it only working for *exact* values?

Comment: @Sinatr: I compute the nearest nominator, e.g. `24` and then try to *simplify* the ratio `24/64` by dividing both `numerator` and `denominator` by the same value (since `64 == 2**6` we can try powers of two): `24/64 == 12 / 32 == 6 / 16 == 3 / 8`

Comment: I see now, thanks for explanation. So you basically extract fractional part, multiply it by denominator, round up and then simplify: 37.4 = 37 + 0.4, then 0.4 = (0.4 * 64 + 0.5) / 64 = 26.1 / 64 ~ 26 / 64 = 13 / 32.

Comment: This solution seems to be working, but I'd like to understand the "int numerator = ..." line. Can you please explain it to me more detailed?

Comment: @Acel: `(Math.Abs(value) - Math.Abs(integer)` - extracting unsigned fractional part (e.g. `-3.128789 -> `0.128789`); `* denominator` - fractional part in `1/64` *units* (`0.128789 -> 8.2425../64`); finally, `(int) (... + 0.5)` - *rounding* (`8.2425..` -> `8`)

Comment: After you get 8.2425 value, in the code you add 0.5 before rounding, so it would be 8.7425, rounded to 9, instead of 8, right? This is the part I don't understand. Why do you need to add 0.5?

Comment: @Acel: `(int)` *doesn't* round it *drops* fractional part; that's the reason to add `0.5`

Answer (score 1):

taking the code of Dmitry Bychenko, we need to add the case "else if (denominator == numerator)" if fraction equals to 1 to add 1 if the value is positive or remove 1 if the value is negative (ex denominator/numerator = 64/64)

```
    private static string ToFraction64(double value)
    {
        // denominator is fixed
        int denominator = 64;
        // integer part, can be signed: 1, 0, -3,...
        int integer = (int)value;
        // numerator: always unsigned (the sign belongs to the integer part)
        // + 0.5 - rounding, nearest one: 37.9 / 64 -> 38 / 64; 38.01 / 64 -> 38 / 64
        int numerator = (int)((Math.Abs(value) - Math.Abs(integer)) * denominator + 0.5);

        // some fractions, e.g. 24 / 64 can be simplified:
        // both numerator and denominator can be divided by the same number
        // since 64 = 2 ** 6 we can try 2 powers only 
        // 24/64 -> 12/32 -> 6/16 -> 3/8
        // In general case (arbitrary denominator) use gcd (Greatest Common Divisor):
        //   double factor = gcd(denominator, numerator);
        //   denominator /= factor;
        //   numerator /= factor;
        while ((numerator % 2 == 0) && (denominator % 2 == 0))
        {
            numerator /= 2;
            denominator /= 2;
        }

        // The longest part is formatting out

        // if we have an actual, not degenerated fraction (not, say, 4 0/1)
        if (denominator > 1)
            if (integer != 0) // all three: integer + numerator + denominator
                return string.Format("{0} {1}/{2}", integer, numerator, denominator);
            else if (value < 0) // negative numerator/denominator, e.g. -1/4
                return string.Format("-{0}/{1}", numerator, denominator);
            else // positive numerator/denominator, e.g. 3/8
                return string.Format("{0}/{1}", numerator, denominator);
        //if fraction equals to 1 we add 1 if the value is positive or remove 1 if the value is negative (ex denominator/numerator = 64/64)
        else if (denominator == numerator)
        {
            if (value < 0) // negative numerator/denominator, e.g. -1/4               
                integer--;
            else // positive numerator/denominator, e.g. 3/8               
                integer++;
            return integer.ToString();
        }
        else
            return integer.ToString(); // just an integer value, e.g. 0, -3, 12...  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Added display of feet

```
public static string ToFraction(this double source, int denominator)
{
    var divider = denominator;
    var inches = (int) Math.Abs(source);
    var numerator = (int) ((Math.Abs(source) - Math.Abs(inches)) * divider + 0.5);

    while (numerator % 2 == 0 && divider % 2 == 0)
    {
        numerator /= 2;
        divider /= 2;
    }

    if (divider == numerator)
    {
        if (source < 0) inches--;
        else inches++;
        numerator = 0;
    }

    var feet = Math.DivRem(inches, 12, out inches);

    var valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (source + 1d / denominator < 0) valueBuilder.Insert(0, "-");

    if (feet > 0)
    {
        valueBuilder.Append(feet);
        valueBuilder.Append("'");
        valueBuilder.Append("-");
    }

    valueBuilder.Append(inches);

    if (numerator != 0)
    {
        valueBuilder.Append(" ");
        valueBuilder.Append(numerator);
        valueBuilder.Append("/");
        valueBuilder.Append(divider);
    }

    valueBuilder.Append('"');
    return valueBuilder.ToString();
}
```

All tests passed

```
    [TestCase]
    public void FractionTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("0\"", 0d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("0\"", (-0d).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("0\"", (-0.00001d).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1\"", 1d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("-1\"", (-1d).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("0 1/8\"", 0.129.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("-0 1/8\"", (-0.129).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("-1 1/4\"", (-1.26378).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("5\"", 5.000001.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("3 1/4\"", 3.24997.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("3 1/4\"", 3.25001.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1'-0\"", 12d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1'-0 3/32\"", 12.1d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1'-1\"", 13d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1'-3 1/8\"", 15.125d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("1'-0\"", 12.00001d.ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("-1'-0\"", (-12.00001d).ToFraction());
        Assert.AreEqual("-2'-1 7/32\"", (-25.231d).ToFraction());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My function is easier and more simple..
It return an array of three integer {*Inches, Numerator, Denominator*} from a decimal value, the **fracBase** argument mean the precision as 16, 32, 64, 128 ....

```
public static int[] GetImpFractions(decimal value, int fracBase = 32)
{
    int[] result = { 0, 0, 0 };

    result[0] = (int)Math.Truncate(value);
    decimal num = (value - (decimal)result[0]);
    num *= fracBase;
    decimal denom = fracBase;
    if (num > 0)
    {
        while (num % 2 == 0) 
        {
            num /= 2;
            denom /= 2;
        }
        if (num == 1 && denom == 1)
        {
            result[0] += 1;
            num = 0; 
            denom = 0;
        }
        result[1] = (int)Math.Truncate(num);
        result[2] = (int)Math.Truncate(denom);
    }

    return result;
}
```